# When and by whom were the Piyutim of Channukah written?

Tags: tefilla, history, chanuka, song-poetry

There are communities that recite special prayers on Shabbos Channukah they begin with אודך כי אנפת ותשוב. Do we know who wrote these and when?

Comment: This piyut was composed by Yosef of Carcassonne, a contemporary of Rashi. Rashi draws from this piyut ("המואסת כל עץ הדקיר המזנה") to interpret "שֵׁבֶט מֹאֶסֶת" in his commentary to *Y'chezkeil 21:18, and that very same section of the piyut seems to be the source for Rashi on *Shabbos* 23a, s.v. *Hayu* ("היו באותו הנס - שגזרו יוונים על כל בתולות הנשואות להיבעל לטפסר תחלה ועל יד אשה נעשה הנס"). See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87545

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author of the *yotzer* "*odecha ki anafta*" was [R. Yosef b. Shelomo of Carcasonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Solomon_of_Carcassonne) (11th century CE).
His signature (יוסף בן שלמה) can be seen in the final line:

> **י**חידך **ו**ידידך **ס**לה **פ**קדוך, **ב**ל **נ**דמית **ש**יגבוך **ל**בדוך, **מ**שבי **ה**דרירם והכל יודוך, קדוש

The *meorah* "*shenei zeitim*" was authored by [R. Shelomo ibn Gabirol](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D) (11th century CE). (The name שלמה is spelled out as an acrostic of the four stanzas.)

And the *zulat* "*ein tzur chelef*" is by [R. Shelomo HaBavli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ben_Judah_ha-Bavli) (10th century CE).
His signature (שלמה הקטן בירבי יהודה חזק) appears in the final lines:

> **ש**מור **ל**פי **מ**ילים **ה**ט **ה**קשב **ק**ובלים **ט**רוד **נ**וף **ב**הולים **י**חיל **ר**וזני **ב**עלים. **י**ציאת **י**ום **ה**ילולים **ו**קרע **ד**ין **ה**וללים **חז**ות **ק**רוא כמהללים מי כמוכה באלים

The above *piyutim* are recited in the Western Ashkenazi tradition. In addition, the Eastern Ashkenazi tradition adds the *ofan* "*kevodo or yazriach*" when it is not also *rosh chodesh*. As far as I can tell, the authorship of this *piyut* is unknown.

---

For completeness' sake, the following *piyutim* are recited on the second *shabbat* of *chanukah* (in a year where that occurs):

In the Western Ashkenazi tradtion, the *yotzer* "*odecha ki anitani*" by [R. Menachem b. Machir](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8) (11th century CE). (In [Mainz](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/180742/p/7/t/1/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c) they would also say the *meorah* "*shenei zeitim*", as on the first *shabbat*.)

In addition to the above, in the Eastern Ashkenazi tradition the following are also recited:

- the *ofan* "*omtzo betofef*", by a [R. Avraham whose identity is unknown](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29119&st=&pgnum=14)
- the *meorah* "*asher yatzar or*", by [R. Ephraim of Regensburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_ben_Isaac_of_Regensburg) (12th century CE)
- the *zulat* "*ein moshia*", also by R. Menachem b. Machir.

Comment: thank you that was very quick! I shall look this up... where did you find this info from?

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy Google! Searching the names of the piyutim (in Hebrew) normally comes up with all the details you need

Comment: We forgot https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&st=&pgnum=262

Comment: @DoubleAA Which elokeichem is said on Shabbat Rosh Chodesh Tevet?

Comment: IINM they are always cumulative and never pushed off (probably due to their length). The order is presumably rosh chodesh first.

Comment: @DoubleAA Seems that in some traditions at least, only the Elokeichem of Rosh Chodesh would be recited https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/minhagim1-2.htm